# str.indexOf is not a function error?

Tags: javascript

Simple, I'm doing this:

```
var loc = window.location;
var fltURI=loc.substr(loc.indexOf("hey?hi=")+7, loc.length);
alert(fltURI);
```

And I'm getting the error.
Please explain also why?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.location is a Location object, and not a string

Try:

```
var loc = window.location.toString();
var fltURI=loc.substr(loc.indexOf("hey?hi=")+7, loc.length);
alert(fltURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

use loc as a string...

```js
var loc = window.location.toString();
alert(loc);
var fltURI=loc.substr(loc.indexOf("hey?hi=")+7, loc.length);
alert(fltURI);
```